# Argument of AND must not return a set when used with BETWEEN in a check constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am encountering the error "argument of AND must not return a set" from the `AND` in the check constraint of the below table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE loan (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   copy_id INTEGER REFERENCES media_copies (copy_id),
   account_id INT REFERENCES account (id),
   loan_date DATE NOT NULL,
   expiry_date DATE NOT NULL,
   return_date DATE,

   CONSTRAINT max_student_concurrent_loans CHECK(
      CurrentStudentLoansCount() BETWEEN 1 AND 7 
   )
);
```

The implementation of `CurrentStudentLoansCount()` is shown below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CurrentStudentLoansCount()
RETURNS TABLE(accid BIGINT) AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM loan
   WHERE account_id IN (SELECT id FROM student)
      AND return_date IS NULL
   GROUP BY account_id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Why am I running into this error and how can I work around it?

For context, the below figure displays my database schema.
[image: database schema]

Comment: Which value exactly do you want to constrain between 1 and 7?

Comment: I want to constraint all values within the table return by `CurrentStudentLoansCount()` between 1 and 7.

Comment: `currentstudentloanscount()` returns a table - potentially millions of rows. You can't use that for a BETWEEN condition.

Comment: `WHERE account_id IN (SELECT id FROM student)` seems strange as well. Why is the student ID the same as the account_id?

Comment: The student ID is the same as the account ID because there exist accounts of different types. For example, student accounts and administrator accounts. All accounts have an ID and if the account ID appears in the student table it means that that account ID belongs to a student, i.e. is a student ID. I will update my post with a database schema for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns a table with multiple rows so you can't use that for a BETWEEN condition. Presumably you just want that value for the account_id of that row of the table (not for all account_ids).

So change the function to return a single value by passing it the account_id. And you also don't need PL/pgSQL for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION currentstudentloanscount(p_account_id integer)
  RETURNS bigint
as
$$
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM loan
  WHERE account_id = p_account_id
    AND return_date IS NULL;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

And change your table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE loan (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   copy_id INTEGER REFERENCES media_copies (copy_id),
   account_id INT REFERENCES account (id),
   loan_date DATE NOT NULL,
   expiry_date DATE NOT NULL,
   return_date DATE,

   CONSTRAINT max_student_concurrent_loans 
       CHECK(currentstudentloanscount(account_id) BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
);
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to define a check constraint that looks at other rows than the current one. This can lead to (data only) dumps that are not reloadable and other oddities. Imagine that the first row inserted for an `account_id` is one with `return_date IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I completely agree - I was just addressing the immediate question